# Integrating Progress Bar for API Call

Tags: python, pandas, progress-bar

**Background:** I have seen lots of examples of integrating a progress bar into a for loop, however nothing for my use case, and as such am looking for some advice.

For my use case, I am calling an API and testing if `meta` is in the response (`meta` = data I need). If `meta` is not in the API response, then the API returns a key pair value named `percent_complete`, which indicates the data I am trying to return is still aggregating, and provides a value on the progress of data aggregation.

**Current code:**

```
def api_call():

    key, secret, url = ini_reader()
    endpoint_url = endpoint_initializer()
    
    while True:
        response = requests.get(url = endpoint_url, auth = HTTPBasicAuth(key, secret), headers = {"vendor-firm": "111"})
        api_response = json.loads(response.text)

        if "meta" not in api_response:
            id_value = "id"
            res1 = [val[id_value] for key, val in api_response.items() if id_value in val]
            id_value = "".join(res1)
            percent_value = "percent_complete"
            res2 = api_response["data"]["attributes"].get("percent_complete", '')*100
            print(f' Your data request for: {id_value} is {res2}% complete!')
            time.sleep(60)

       elif "meta" in api_response:
            
     return api_response
```

**What I am trying to achieve:** `{res2}` *100 gives the percentage, which I would like to use the measure of progress in a progress bar.

Can anyone suggest an appropriate dependency to use?

Comment: Thanks @KarlThornton , I'll take a peek at this and report back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [Enlighten](https://pypi.org/project/enlighten/) library. You can keep your print statements and have multiple progress bars at the same time without making any other changes. Below is an example of how you might implement it.

Based on your example it looks like `id_value` changes, so I wrote the example like that. If it doesn't change you can just use it in the description. And if you have multiples, you'd probably want to create a progress bar for each. If you want to remove your progress bars after they complete, just add `leave=False` to `manager.Counter()`.

The library is very customizable and the [documentation](https://python-enlighten.readthedocs.io) has a lot of [examples](https://python-enlighten.readthedocs.io/en/stable/examples.html).

```
import enlighten

BAR_FORMAT = u'{id_value} {percentage:3.0f}%|{bar}| ' u'[{elapsed}<{eta}, {rate:.2f} %/s]'

manager = enlighten.get_manager()

def api_call():
    pbar = manager.counter(total=100, bar_format=BAR_FORMAT)
    ...
    while True:
        ...
    if "meta" not in api_response:
        ...
        pbar.count = res2
        pbar.update(incr=0, id_value=id_value)

    else:
        ...
        pbar.count = 100
        pbar.update(incr=0, id_value=id_value)

    pbar.close()
    return api_response
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Aviso, and for everyone's benefit, here is the completed function -

```
def api_call():
    endpoint_url = endpoint_initializer()
    key, secret, url = ini_reader()
    
    BAR_FORMAT = u'{id_value} {percentage:3.0f}%|{bar}| ' u'[{elapsed}<{eta}, {rate:.2f} %/s]'
    manager = enlighten.get_manager()
    
    date = dt.datetime.today().strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
    print("------------------------------------\n","API URL constructed for:", date, "\n------------------------------------")
    print("-------------------------------------------------------------\n","Endpoint:", endpoint_url, "\n-------------------------------------------------------------") 
    
    pbar = manager.counter(total=100, bar_format=BAR_FORMAT)

    while True:
        response = requests.get(url = endpoint_url, auth = HTTPBasicAuth(key, secret), headers = {"vendor-firm": "381"})
        api_response = json.loads(response.text) 
        
        if "meta" not in api_response:
            id_value = "id"
            res1 = [val[id_value] for key, val in api_response.items() if id_value in val]
            id_value = "".join(res1)
            percent_value = "percent_complete"
            res2 = api_response["data"]["attributes"].get("percent_complete", '')*100
            pbar.count = res2
            pbar.update(incr=0, id_value=id_value)
            time.sleep(60)
        
        elif "meta" in api_response:
            pbar.count = 100
            pbar.update(incr=0, id_value=id_value)
            pbar.close()
            return api_response
```